# How to change into directory owned by root if I have sudo?

Tags: command-line, sudo, cd-command

I have a deploy user that has `sudo` privledges.

I can't `sudo cd` into the directory, but I can list it like:

```
sudo ls /root
```

How can I `cd` into the folder, or is that not possible?

Answer (score 11):

It is not possible, because `sudo` runs a single command as root; your shell is still owned by your user.

What you *can* do is to open a new shell as root, by running `sudo -i` or `sudo -s`. From `man sudo`:

> ```
>  -i, --login
>                Run the shell specified by the target user's password data-
>                base entry as a login shell.
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> ```
>  -s, --shell
>               Run the shell specified by the SHELL environment variable if
>               it is set or the shell specified by the invoking user's pass-
>               word database entry.  If a command is specified, it is passed
>               to the shell for execution via the shell's -c option.  If no
>               command is specified, an interactive shell is executed.
> ```

Either of these will give you a new shell, with root privileges, where you can freely change directory and run new commands as root.

Answer (score 8):

`cd` is a shell builtin command . You can't use it directly with `sudo`.

Use

```
sudo -i
```

to get a root shell and then `cd` into the folder you want.

If you don't need root privileges anymore use

```
exit
```

or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> to exit the root shell.